# Python Package with inter-Modul Dependencies

Tags: python-import, python-module, python-packaging

My Folder Structure looks like the following

```
person-package
|- __init__.py
|- person.py
|- person_manager.py
main.py
```

`person_manager.py` imports `person.py`

```
import person as x
```

The `main.py` imports `person_manager.py`

```
import person_package.person_manager as x
```

When running  `main.py` I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'person'
```

I know, I could solve that by changing the import of `person_manager.py` to the following

```
from . import person as x
```

However, when running now `person_manager.py` directly, I get:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So I can't test `person_manager.py` on its own.
What is the most elegant way to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***1.*** I recommend to always use absolute imports (unless strictly impossible).

***2.*** `person-package` is not a valid Python name since it contains a dash `-`, if I were you I would rename to `person_package` with an underscore `_`.

***3.*** Since `person_manager.py` is part of a Python importable package (i.e. it is in a directory containing a `__init__.py` file), then it should not be run as `python person_package/person_manager.py`, but as `python -m person_package.person_manager`.